# Unit test for remote call at ngOnInt

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Here is my component:

```
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    me: User;  
    let userServiceGetMeSpy; 

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.userService.getMe().subscribe(user => {

          this.me = user;
```

At the start of component at ngOnit I am calling a service to a do a remote call and get the user object, then I am setting the returned object to component's "me" property.

My goal is to write a unit test to check if the me property is set after successfully calling getMe method of UserService from ngOnit method.

I can think on this code for spec:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let userService: UserService;
  let mockedUser = new User();

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);


    mockedUser.Name = "Admin User";

    userServiceGetMeSpy = spyOn(userService, "getMe").and.callFake(() => {
      return of<User>(mockedUser)
    })

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

I am having confusion for the unit test to write:

```
  it('should set "me" property on calling getMe at ngOnit on MyComponent', () => {

    //What to write here?

  });
```

I can think of a test which will detect whether the call to getMe method has been made or not

```
  it('should have called user service get me on page load', () => {

    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(userServiceGetMeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I need to get further and check whether "me" property has been called or not after that call.

Comment: Unit tests should not check the server, therefore you can just mock the data returned and check it in your component

Comment: I have already mocked it. I have mentioned that in my question:  userServiceGetMeSpy = spyOn(userService, "getMe").and.callFake(() => {
      return of<User>(mockedUser)
    })

Comment: `expect(component.me).toBe(mockedUser);`?

Comment: getMe is not a static method but a remote call returning observable. Where should I put the subscribe for getme?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `userServiceGetMeSpy` from `MyComponent` class. The only thing you need is mocking the service call `UserService.getMe` before the component's `ngOnInit` is invoked.

```
spyOn(userService, 'getMe').and.returnValue(of(user));
```

Please note that `fixture.detectChanges` triggers a change detection cycle for the component and implicitly invokes its `ngOnInit` method. Therefore, no need to explicitly call `ngOnInit` in your test again.

You can write your test as follows.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  const user = new User();
  let userService: UserService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    spyOn(userService, 'getMe').and.returnValue(of(user));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should have called user service get me on page load', () => {
    expect(userService.getMe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.me).toBe(user);
  });
});
```

Comment: getMe is returning observable. How to make sure that getMe has returned the response, only then we can confirm whether the me has been set or or not. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: The `userService.getMe` mock delivers the user in a synchronous way using `of`.  `expect(component.me).toBe(user);` confirms that `me` has been set.